# One sentence answers

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

Over the past few days, we have seen a couple of answers on the [Is it legal to throw an alley-oop to yourself in a real game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/324/is-it-legal-to-throw-an-alley-oop-to-yourself-in-a-real-game) thread having just a sentence. Mind you, the answers aren't wrong but they are just blunt to-the-point answers.

Should such answers be encouraged?

Comment: As an aside, the current [FAQ](http://sports.stackexchange.com/faq) was introduced in response to a popular meta question regarding [relevance](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/278/527). Other SE sites inform users of which [content is encouraged/discouraged](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq)...which I indirectly attempt to address [here](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/312/527). We are still in beta, so expect improvements. FAQ info: [questions](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/256/527) and [answers](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/257/527).

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the [FAQ section about what a good answer is](https://sports.stackexchange.com/faq):

> **Is it supported by "authority?**" Back up claims by referencing sources. This is particularly important when discussing rules.
>   **Can I provide a unique perspective?** Add something new. If you have insight to add to another user's answer, consider doing so in a comment.
>   **Can I share my personal experience(s)?** Expertise shines through.

The question was answered previously by a few users which was supported by evidence from various sources. The two new answers do not offer anything new, perspective-wise or source-wise. Yes, there are some questions where you cannot give references and can only speak through experience of playing, watching or understanding the sport. But this, hardly, was such a question.

My personal opinion is that, when one is trying to learn things about a game through Sports SE, having answers that contain links from credible sources go a long way in helping them understand the intricacies of the sport, than just a one line Yes/No answer.

Comment: I agree **for those answers**.  I also agree that, "I'm certified" is like saying, "I'm a rocket scientist." But this should be evaluated on a case-by-case basis.